# Meta Refresh without URL Rewrite

Tags: php, html, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

We're launching a members-only Wordpress site that is only capable of hiding pages/posts; however, part of our content is served up by an API that can't easily be hidden.

My best solution thus far is to embed an html meta redirect to the appropriate URL on a page that I can restrict using our Memberships plugin.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://www.example.com/?taxonomy=inventory" />
```

The only caveat to this method is that the URL is then exposed, and anyone could distribute the source.

Is there any way to use the meta redirect without rewriting the URL? I've tried a few things in the .htaccess file, but nothing has really yielded a viable solution.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a meta refresh (which can easily be blocked with the right browser plugin), you should instead focus on adding a page and post hook that checks if the viewer has the appropriate permissions (logged in, member, etc) to view that page and redirect them server-side back to the homepage (or a custom error page).

This may not prevent the hidden page links from being shared, but it will prevent the content from being read.

Comment: The Memberships plugin we're using is dual purpose for something completely unrelated to this, and we're not prepared to give it up... thus I'm forced to make nice with it. Distribution of URLs is something we simply can't allow, so somehow... I must mask the URL during the redirect.

Comment: You cannot prevent end-users from sharing URLs, unless you use one-time URLs that never go to the same content twice. If you need to mask the URL then create a buffer URL that is handled by wordpress and sends them to the real URL after checking their membership status. You will have to give-way somewhere to make this work.

Comment: Explain a little more about this buffer URL. I'm new to this concept.

Comment: You can use a plugin that marks pages with custom information or redirect all post/page requests to a specific wordpress file. Then you can check if they are logged in and have access to view the post/page, if it's required. If everything aside from the homepage is supposed to be members only, you can just check if they're logged in and have access on the post.php and page.php files, and voila.